# Wifi not availaible

Tags: wireless, internet-radio, centrino

Wifi is not working and cannot get access activate the wifi. Always getting message wifi unavailable, Radio switch off. The machine doesn't have way to activate manually it's supposed to switch on automatically.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2501 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 064e:8120 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:3008 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output from several `lspci` calls are:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
04:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7231 (rev ca)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)

fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snb_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
04:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7231 (rev ca)
    Subsystem: Avermedia Technologies Inc SAA7231
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Output from `lshw` is:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ     
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: wlp3s0
       version: 34
       numéro de série: 88:53:2e:c9:c1:06
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       ressources: irq:32 mémoire:fb000000-fb001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:05:00.0
       nom logique: enp5s0
       version: 06
       numéro de série: 00:21:70:68:68:de
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.77 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources: irq:29 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:e2104000-e2104fff mémoire:e2100000-e2103fff
```

Output from `lsmod` is:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  0
bnep                   20480  2
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
ufs                    73728  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus               106496  0
hfs                    57344  0
minix                  36864  0
ntfs                   98304  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   180224  0
xfs                   970752  0
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
arc4                   16384  2
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
iwldvm                233472  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
hid_multitouch         20480  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 20480  0
snd_hda_core           73728  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
dell_wmi_aio           16384  0
gpio_ich               16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi_aio
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             172032  0
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
btusb                  45056  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
dcdbas                 16384  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd                    81920  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
cryptd                 20480  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
8250_fintek            16384  0
mei_me                 36864  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
lpc_ich                24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  3 hid_multitouch,hid_generic,usbhid
nouveau              1495040  0
i915                 1208320  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
ahci                   36864  2
drm_kms_helper        147456  2 i915,nouveau
libahci                32768  1 ahci
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
r8169                  81920  0
drm                   360448  4 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    20480  3 dell_wmi_aio,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  2 i915,nouveau
fjes                   28672  0
```

Output from `iwconfig` is:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Output from `ifconfig` is:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ ifconfig
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:70:68:68:de  
          inet adr:192.168.1.77  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::6497:ff1b:1d54:b503/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:2089 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:553542 (553.5 KB) Octets transmis:223624 (223.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:337 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1 
          Octets reçus:29340 (29.3 KB) Octets transmis:29340 (29.3 KB)
```

Output from `iwlist` is:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ sudo iwlist scan
wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Kernel info:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ uname -r -m 
4.4.0-31-generic x86_64
```

Other bits:

```
fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ cat  /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ nm-tool
La commande « nm-tool » est introuvable, vouliez-vous dire :
 La commande « dm-tool » du paquet « lightdm » (main)
nm-tool : commande introuvable

fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

fred@fred-Inspiron-One-2320:~$ nmcli connection show
NOM                  UUID                                  TYPE             PÉRIPHÉRIQUE 
enp5s0               1c159d44-aeeb-45ff-aeb7-bb72d7701d8d  802-3-ethernet   enp5s0       
Connexion Wi-Fi 1    8faae169-af2a-45df-934e-7dbe17974504  802-11-wireless  --           
Connexion filaire 1  1d435d80-2947-45d1-87e5-c8b7f4a0fc56  802-3-ethernet   --
```

Comment: Run `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"` and reboot.